# Change indentation format of a list of numbered items

Tags: lists, tcolorbox

[image]

How may the indicated formatting choice be implemented using LaTeX methods?

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white!100!white]
\textbf{Elementary row operations (Def)} \\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{flushleft}
Since the rows (horizontal lines) of an augmented matrix correspond to the equations in
the associated system, these three operations correspond to the following operations on
the rows of the augmented matrix:\\
 \bigbreak
1. Multiply a row through by a nonzero \\ \qaud constant.\\
2. Interchange two rows.\\
3. Add a constant times one row to another.\\
\bigbreak
These are called elementary row operations on a matrix.
\end{flushleft}


\end{tcolorbox}
```

Comment: You might (semantically) use an `enumerate` environment. That also possess the possibility to fix indentation. Also make sure to include MWEs in you questions to get direct help form others :)

Comment: @Ronny - Sort of like in the way I've suggested in my answer? :-)

Comment: Why are there (already) two votes to close this posting as "unclear what you're asking"? I'd say it's perfectly clear what the objective is.

Comment: Indeed I voted to close, because there is no real question asked, no explaining text, my comment was merely a wild guess; but yes I meant something like you answered.

Comment: @Ronny - Thanks for this follow-up. I've gone ahead and changed the posting's title and added a "real question" to the body of the posting.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you load the `enumitem` package and use an `enumerate` environment for the three numbered items, setting the options `noitemsep`, `itemindent=*` , and `leftmargin=*` to achieve the formatting objectives you've outlined in the screenshot you posted. Note that with this adjustment, it's no longer necessary -- or, for that matter, *desirable* -- to insert all those `\\` line-break directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,enumitem}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth{\mylen}{\textbf{Elementary row operations (Def)}}
\addtolength{\mylen}{5\tabcolsep}
\begin{document}
\noindent
% Optional: Encase the "tcolorbox" environment in a "minipage" of a certain width
\begin{minipage}{\mylen}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white!100!white]
\raggedright % easier than "flushleft" environment
\textbf{Elementary row operations (Def)}

\medskip % or, "\bigskip" if you want even more vertical separation
Since the rows (horizontal lines) of an augmented matrix correspond to the equations in
the associated system, these three operations correspond to the following operations on
the rows of the augmented matrix:
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep,itemindent=*,leftmargin=*]
\item Multiply a row through by a nonzero constant.
\item Interchange two rows.
\item Add a constant times one row to another.
\end{enumerate}
These are called elementary row operations on a matrix.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you have lots of instances of such enumerated lists, it may become tedious to have to remember to type

```
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep,itemindent=*,leftmargin=*]
```

every single time. Instead, you may define a customized `enumerate`-like list called, say, `myenum` as follows:

```
\newlist{myenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenum]{noitemsep,itemindent=*,leftmargin=*,
                 label=\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*}
```

and then use `\begin{myenum}` and `\end{myenum}` throughout the document whenever you need it.